# Verifying Solutions for Quadratic Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying Algebra 1, focusing on Quadratic Equations. I've learned the Quadratic Formula for solving them and want to practice verifying solutions by substituting them back into the original equation.

I came across this Problem: $ 3x^2 - 6x - 17 = 0 $

Using the Quadratic Formula, the solution is: $$ x = \frac {3 \pm 2\sqrt{15}} {3} $$

I attempted to verify the positive solution, but I keep getting incorrect results.

Those are my Steps to check $ x = \frac {3 + 2\sqrt{15}} {3} $

```
- Plug in the solution for x
```

$$ 3[\frac {3 + 2\sqrt{15}} {3}]^2 -6[\frac {3 + 2\sqrt{15}} {3}] - 17 = 0 $$

```
- Squaring each term within the larger first term.
```

$$ 3[\frac {9 + 60} {9}] -6[\frac {3 + 2\sqrt{15}} {3}] - 17 = 0 $$

We arrived at 60 by squaring both the 2 and the $\sqrt{15}$ separately, resulting in 4 * 15, which equals 60.

```
- Simplifying each term
```

$$ 23 -6 -2\sqrt{15} - 17 = 0 $$

The 23 resulted from canceling a common factor of 3 between the denominator (9) and the factor that multiplied the entire parenthesis (3). This cancellation simplified $\frac{69}{3}$ to 23. Similarly, we canceled a common factor of 3 between the numbers $-6$ and the denominator (3).

```
- Adding like terms together
```

$$ 23 - 23 -2\sqrt{15} = 0 $$

$$-2\sqrt{15} = 0 $$

Starting with $ 23 - 23 = 0 $, which simplifies to $ -2√15 = 0 $

Clearly, I made an error somewhere in my calculations. I just don't know where. I'm curious about what happened with $ -2\sqrt{15} $

Anyways, where did I make mistakes in my calculations? Thanks for the time and help. Have a great day.

Comment: Notice that 3+2√ 15 squared is not 9 + 60, but is rather 9 + 12√ 15 + 60 instead. (x+y)^2 is not equal to x^2 + y^2- its equal to x^2 + 2xy + y^2.

Answer (score 1):

Note the identity $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.

$$(\frac{3+2\sqrt{15}}{3})^2=\frac{(3+2\sqrt{15})^2}{3^2}\\
=\frac{3^2+2\times3\times2\sqrt{15}+(2\sqrt{15})^2}{9}\\
=\frac{69+12\sqrt{15}}{9}=\frac{23+4\sqrt{15}}{3}$$

Besides,

$$-6(\frac{3+2\sqrt{15}}{3})-17=-23-\color{red}4\sqrt{15}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(a+b)^2 \not= a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you are being so diligent checking your work like that!

Another check on your answer is finding them in a different ways.

Consider this:

Start: $(a+b)(c+d)$

Distribute: a(c+d)+b(c+d)

Distribute again: $ac+ad +bc+bd$

Let $c=a$ and $d=b$

Then: $ac+ad+bc+bd=a^2+ab+ba+b^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

Thus $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ as mentioned else where.

It's important not to just memorize formulas, but know where they come from. Have you learned completing the square? They skipped it in my algebra class. Very unfortunate. It can be used to derive the quadratic formula.

Suppose $ax^2+bx+c=0$

$ax^2+bx+c=a[x^2+(b/a)x+c/a]$: divide by the coefficient of x^2

$a[x^2+(b/a)x+c/a] = [x^2+(b/a)x+ (b^2/4a^2 - b^2/4a^2) +c/a]$ : Add a form of zero (in parentheses).

$[ [x^2+(b/a)x+ b^2/4a^2] - b^2/4a^2 +c/a]=0$ Change parentheses location via associativity.

$ [ [x+(b/2a)]^2 -b^2/4a^2+c/a ]=0$ :factor using $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ backwards.

$[x+ (b/2a)]^2 = b^2/4a^2-c/a= \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$ : Add the inverse to both sides and express as a single fraction using the common denominator.

$x + b/2a = \pm \sqrt{ \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}= \frac{\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$x= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ : The quadratic formula.

This used completing the square to derive the quadratic formula. There are other ways to do it, but that's probably the most straight forward. Did you know there's also a cubic formula? There's also one for 4th powers, but none for 5th powers on up.